# vim Mac OS X install with gui-support

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I have *Mac Pro, with OS X 10.9.4* (can't upgrade to Yosemite yet), and I'm trying to build **vim7.4 with gui-support**, or get any kind of gui-support. My current vim is version 7.3, I'm guessing, that's the default vim that ships with macs. I have the **Terminal.app** and **iTerm2.app**, my vim rc has the default

```
set term=xterm-256colors
```

or what have you.

What I have so far:

```
macvim
```

The colors look great, basically it's the same setup I had on my ubuntu system, but it's really annoying that it opens a new window. **Is there a way to get it to open within my terminal? (not launch it from the terminal, open inside of it)**

As I've said I have the regular vim7.3
And while I can use color-schemes, they look like garbage compared to my ubuntu system. I suppose this must be due to gui-support option? I tried, CSApprox but that gives me a weird error.

So I decided to simply build vim 7.4 and enable gui support, but I get random errors.
My basic config make looks like:

```
./configure --enable-gui=yes
make
```

At which point it complains about missing header file etc. , I figured this should not be that hard.

Any tips?

The basics of what I'm trying to do is:

*Have a vim version installed with gui-support, or a work-around where my colors are all screwed up.*

Thanks!

Comment: open inside terminal gui-app?

Comment: yeah, like $vim will simply open in the console, but macvim, will open in a new window. Ideally, I want macvim to open inside the console, not a new window.

Comment: do you tried `gvim`?

Comment: I did not, or I may have, but from past I thought gvim doesn't run in the console either, it opens a new window, no?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building Vim on Mac OS X is a waste of time.

Step 1: Download the appropriate MacVim build from [here](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases).

Step 2: Put MacVim.app into the `/Applications/` directory.

Step 3: Put the bundled `mvim` script somewhere in your `PATH`.

Done.

To run MacVim *in* your shell:

```
$ mvim -v filename
```

To run MacVim *from* your shell:

```
$ mvim filename
```

Comment: @janjust I might also add that if you are using the excellent [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) `brew` application, you can install MacVIM using the command `brew install macvim --with-lua --with-luajit`. This has the advantage that you can simply run `brew upgrade macvim` to get the latest version.

Comment: @shaond Are the Lua flags necessary for any of the built in features, or are they just for custom scripts/plugins?

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy, `+lua` is only used by a handful of plugins.

Comment: Only problem with MacVim is that it's behind the times. As of this date, McVim is  V8.1.577, whereas Vim is V8.1.682. And you cannot have both Vim and MacVim installed (without name changes) because they both install the same binaries.

Comment: @JESii lagging by a hundred patches means MacVim is stable and yes, you can have MacVim installed alongside any other Vim.

Comment: ‘Stability’ issues with brew vim have been next to zero in all my years, so my preference is for patches. Some delay is fine, IMO, but there’s a limit for me. And even with the suggestions below, I’ve not been able to get the GUI option to stick.

Answer (score 6):

Building Vim with GUI on macOS using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

1. `brew edit vim`.
2. Add a new line with `option` for GUI:

   ```
   option "enable-gui", "Enable GUI mode"
   ```
3. Change from `no` to `yes` in the following line:

   ```
   opts << "--enable-gui=no"
   ```
4. Install or re-install vim:

   ```
   brew reinstall vim --enable-gui
   ```

---

Troubleshooting:

- If you've errors related to Python 3, see: [vim's GH-2754](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2754).
- Checkout new Homebrew PR at [GH-25785](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/25785) with above patch.